# NSUseractivity not working from apple watch to iphone app

Tags: ios, handoff

I am implementing handoff from an apple watch app to the destination app on my iphone.

On one of the WatchKit Extension viewcontrollers i have the following code:

```
myActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc]
                              initWithActivityType: @"com.newsApp.shownews"];
myActivity.userInfo = @{@"newsID":[self.newsID objectAtIndex:0]};
myActivity.title = @"shownews";
myActivity.delegate = self;
[myActivity becomeCurrent];
```

Then i add the following code in the `continueUserActivity` inside the appDelegate of my destination iphone app:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
{
    if ([userActivity.activityType  isEqual: @"com.newsApp.shownews"]) {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
        ShownewsViewController *detailViewController = (ShownewsViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShownewsViewController"];

        detailViewController.post_ID = [userActivity.userInfo objectForKey:@"newsID"];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }   
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is that `userActivity.userInfo` is empty but the `userActivity.activityType` is correctly set to `com.newsApp.shownews`.

Comment: Epic fail for me ! NSUserActivity doesn't work on my Xcode 7. 
Followed exactly the documentation of Apple, and I get nothing in my research on Spotlight...

Comment: @manonthemoon i use xcode 6.3

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [requiredUserInfoKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSUserActivity/requiredUserInfoKeys) on your NSUserActivity object.

Answer (score 0):

For continue the **Activity**  from **Watch** to **iPhone** App use NSUserActivity Xcode 8  Swift-3 :-

[image]

**Watch Target:**

```
@IBAction func navigateToiPhoneApp() {
      //  let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "WatchKitHandoff.Notification.com")
        //userActivity.ac
        self.updateUserActivity("com.WatchKit.Notification.", userInfo:["key":"value"], webpageURL:nil)
    }
```

**iPhone  Target:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
            print("continue activity2")
            restorationHandler([self.window!.rootViewController!])
            return true
        }
```

**Update info.plist** 
[image]

*Simulator do not support Handoff in till Xcode-8.1*